# What can be done about an incorrect "you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period" block?

Tags: support, proxy, post-ban, ip-address

I just attempted to ask my first question ever on Stack Overflow, but the system told me

> Sorry, you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period

What can I do about this?

EDIT from comments:
Aarghhh... I have a public IP, but it goes through a proxy and the IP gets rewritten. Is there some way SO could determine my posting authorization based on my login credentials and not IP? Maybe a whitelist to which users can be added after raising Meta posts like this one and confirming their registration? For now, I will take my questions to another forum.

Comment: Have you created any other accounts on Stack Overflow before?

Comment: Have you deleted any questions?

Comment: Are you connecting through a proxy?

Comment: Awww, sucks when the IP catches up with you.

Comment: What Hans is saying: You probably share an IP with other SO users, and _from this IP_ it's already 50 questions.

Comment: Or you've asked 50 questions from another account, which would have the same IP address as this new account you created.

Comment: Aarghhh.. I have a public IP but its going through a proxy and the IP is being re-written. Is there somehow stackoverflow site would be able to determine based on the login credentials and not the IP, maybe a white-list to which users can be added after raising a meta-post and confirming their registration. 
For now will take my doubts to another forum

Comment: @jwookie If you want more responses, update your question with this new information. I'd actually be interested in knowing what, if any, recourse is available for people who haven't done anything wrong but are being blocked from Stack Overflow simply because they are behind a proxy that is rewriting IP addresses.

Answer (score 2):

> I have a public IP

I suggest you not use that public IP.  It will be an uphill battle to convince Stack Exchange that a proxy IP should be whitelisted.

Alternately, use a proxy, or create your own with a free webhost that supports PHP.

Comment: The underlying nature itself is that of "identifying trusted identities". Sites like craigslist, ebay etc have similar issues. Words that the website uses like "high quality posts" is hard to quantify in Maths thus in program.
I am sure given the selective domain and the huge collection of posts in the website there can be relations and data be mined for accepting posts and then this can be tuned.
Any takers?

Comment: @jwookie As you probably noticed Stack Overflow optimizes for answers, not questions.  We have a multitude of questions.  So, quite frankly, unless someone presents a compelling case to go to all the work you suggest, they aren't going to spend time to do so when they have a solution that works well enough for the purpose at hand.

Comment: Makes sense to think from "optimizes for answers" POV. The case itself could be worthy of some serious thought to trusted identities but then again its more of a research question.
Thanks guys for the comments.