# Not able to ask question in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, asking-questions

After pressing "Post your Question" button getting this error:

> You can only ask 50 questions in a 30-day period.

on a red background.

However without asking a single question in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2439275/newbie-user).

See the screen shot.

> [image]

Comment: read and accepted the check box and pressed Proceed,i edited my question,so while clicking POST YOUR QUESTION i am getting this error "You can only ask 50 questions in a 30-day period." in a red bachground.Not able to updae the screen shot as i don't have 10 reputation

Comment: You may want to add some detail to your post here, like the fact that your account is brand new and thus hasn't been around long enough to ask 50 questions in 30 days, and a more complete description of what you did.

Comment: And did you have an account with Stack Overflow before this one?

Comment: More information here: [What can be done about an incorrect “you are only allowed to ask 50 questions in a 30 day period” block?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102627/what-can-be-done-about-an-incorrect-you-are-only-allowed-to-ask-50-questions-in)

Comment: Why does this look like a bug? Are you trying to say you didn't actually ask that many questions?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i don't have account with SO

Comment: @JoshCaswell: The account has *zero* questions and was created today. Not a dupe of that post, I don't think.

Comment: In all likelihood you share your IP with a bunch of people, who used up the 50 questions. Is it possible to try accessing the site from a different IP?

Comment: @foo: The original question was devoid of all information, so at least *some* of the downvotes are fully defensible.

Comment: Are you sure that's the account about which this complaint is being made, @MartijnPieters? Some evidence (a screenshot showing the error message and account name?) would be nice.

Comment: I upvoted first :) I think incomplete question got downvote.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: Let's assume so; the OP is probably using a public IP address and hit the per-IP limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message explicitly describe the problem:

> You can only ask 50 questions in a 30-day period.

There's a limit for how many questions you are allowed to ask within 30-days (1 month), probably in order to limit spam or help vampires. I suggest you to wait until the next week or month and try again.

50 questions per month is quite a large number though.

---

Apparently this was indeed a problem because the user never posted a single question. This problem is caused by the usage of a public IP. The only [known solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/102627/152998) is to use a proxy.

Comment: But,howcome without asking a single question,SO will tell this msg

Comment: @SivaRamR, are you sure you are using this account? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: don't have 10 reputation,so not possible

Comment: @SivaRamR - Just give the link of the image. We will do that for you.

Comment: @SivaRamR, the ability to take a screenshot does not depend on the reputation.

Comment: Screen shot of the error part uploaded

Comment: @SivaRamR, do you use a public IP?

Comment: yes,i am using a browsing coffae

Comment: @SivaRamR, see edit.

Comment: @Jeffrey i got it,i think some other people also using this service,so i am not able to loggin,Thank for you suggestion