# resolving an incorrect "You can only ask xxx questions in a xxx period"

Tags: support

I'm told I can't post on SO because I have asked 50 questions in 30 days.

I haven't.

[I'm not behind a corporate firewall](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118375/reached-50-questions-limit-with-only-6-questions). [Other users on my network don't have an SE accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93738/50-questions-30-days-limit-with-only-2-questions-posted?lq=1).  [I'm not using a proxy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102627/what-can-be-done-about-an-incorrect-you-are-only-allowed-to-ask-50-questions-in). I have deleted about 3 questions (not 30). I don't have a fake account.

What do I do?

Comment: Is this a real stackedOverflow rule? Can you share this reference?

Comment: @javaPlease42 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89217/50-question-per-month-limit

Comment: @javaPlease42 I have no idea, it just says "You can only ask 50 questions in a 30-day period." when I try to post, and doesn't let me submit the question.

Comment: Using the data query explorer http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/147556#resultSets returns a value of 48 for past 30 days. If you have 2 or more deleted questions that means you have more than 50.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I count 49 questions in your SO user profile, if you've deleted 3 that puts you at 52 questions in the last 30 days... 2 over the limit.